# Assigning NSDictionary keys to NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, nssortdescriptor

I'm importing a txt file with a list of first and last names. Each new name is on it's own line, so I imported them into a NSMutableArray and then split them with componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n". I then want to sort the names via their last name. I have found this [Sort collections](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html), but I'm lost at how I would tell my NSStrings that are within my Array to have the key's firstName and lastName. Obviously I'd have to make an NSDictionary, but can you do a for loop where by I say something like anything before the " " (space) is firstName, and anything after is the lastName.

Hopefully I've been clear enough,

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is all going to be displayed in a UITableView, if that changes/helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would make a simple class called Name that has a property for firstName and a property for lastName. You can then loop through the array and to create your Name instances, add them to an NSMutableArray and then sort the array. You can go the dictionary route if you want of course.

Here is an example:

```
NSMutableArray *namesList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

for (NSString *name in originalArray) {
  NSArray *tempArray = [name componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
  Name *newNameInstance = [[Name alloc] init];
  newNameInstance.firstName = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];
  newNameInstance.lastName = [tempArray objectAtIndex:1];
  [namesList addObject:newNameInstance];
}

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName"
                                              ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [namesList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

This code hasn't been checked but it should work. I haven't taken care with memory management so please be mindful of that.

**Update**
Sorry, should be [tempArray objectAtIndex:0]. Fixed it above.

Since firstName and lastName are strings then they should be declared as NSString. Try not to use id for a property unless you have a really good reason.

**Update 2**
If you want to check the values do this:

```
for (Name *name in sortedArray) {
   NSLog(@"%@", name.firstname);
   NSLog(@"%@", name.lastName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! A couple questions though, in the Name class, does properties mean like NSString or id for firstName and lastName. Also, it says NSString may not respond to objectAtIndex. Would tempArray go in there instead? Sorry I'm still fairly new at Obj-C.

Comment: I'm not getting any more errors, but when I NSLOG namesList, I get this: `"<Name: 0x4b420d0>", "<Name: 0x4b983c0>", "<Name: 0x4b98430>",` Also, when I created the new simple class, was that supposed to be it's own file with @property and @synthesize or just a new class method within the original file? Maybe that is where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Displaying namesList should display a Name object for the number of names in the original list/2.

Comment: The NSLog is correct because you have not created a description method for your Name class so it is simply logging the memory address. The Name class should be its own file, it looks like you have that done correctly. What you should do with the sortedArray is to enumerate through it and in the loop log name.firstName and name.Last name.

Comment: Sorry I've never done this before. So you'd make a for loop based on sortedArray, but then I'm not sure how to work in name.firstName with the array. It keeps coming back with the memory address.

Comment: Updated for the sortedArary loop.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I've still got to put this into a UITableView, but hopefully I can work that one out for myself :/